# Angular Validation| ng-required Usage for input group

Tags: angularjs, validation, required

I have set of two input group,i want either one to be required.
As in

- If value in one group is entered then ng-required for other should be false
- Vice Versa for the other group.

How do i do this with help of angular validations.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="myForm" action="FileUpload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate name="signup_form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-left">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="employer">Corporate Name
                            <span ng-show="!signup_form.maid.$valid">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input name="employer" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="form.employer" ng-required="!signup_form.maid.$valid">
                            <div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.employer.$dirty && signup_form.employer.$invalid">
                                <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.employer.$error.required">
                                                                                        Employer name is required.
                                                                                    </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="empid">Employee ID 
                                <span ng-show="!signup_form.maid.$valid">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="empid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="form.empid" ng-required="!signup_form.maid.$valid">
                                <div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.empid.$dirty && signup_form.empid.$invalid">
                                    <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.empid.$error.required">
                                                                                        Employee ID is required.
                                                                                    </small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="badge">OR</div>
                <div class="col-md-5  pull-right" ng-show="!form.isgovtscheme ">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="maid">MAID *</label>
                                <input name="maid" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="form.maid" ng-required="!(signup_form.empid.$valid && signup_form.employer.$valid)">
                                    <div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.maid.$dirty && signup_form.maid.$invalid">
                                        <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.maid.$error.required">
                                                                                        MAID is required and should contain only numbers.
                                                                                    </small>
                                        <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.maid.$error.number">
                                                                                        MAID can contain only numbers
                                                                                    </small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start" ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid && !PreAuthForIR && !form.isgovtscheme" id="newAdmissionButton">
                    <span>Submit New Admission</span>
                </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: you wants to say if one input has value then no need of value in second input, am i right.

Comment: Yes exactly what you said.

Comment: try this  ng-required = "!signup_form.maid.$valid || !form.empid==''"